# Is it possible to fetch object in OkObjectResult 200 response?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Is it possible to fetch object in OkObjectResult 200 response?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetMyObject(int objectId)
{
…
return this.Ok(myObject);
}
```

Is it possible to access the 'myObject' or only the OkResponse

Comment: Hi there! Where (and when) do you want to access _myObject_ object? On client side, or on server?

Comment: Please add more information to your question. if your using a http client you can use `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();` Which will throw exception if not success

Comment: This might a good resource to start with

Comment: Where and how you want to access the myObject

Comment: I’m trying to access it client side. For the moment I’m trying to do it in a UnitTest using a moq and then fetching it but maybe that’s not the best way to go?